# Проверка метода класса на существование

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Имеется абстрактный класс `AbstractClass` и несколько классов-наследников, в одном из которых определен метод `Method`. Имеется еще один метод `Method2`, в который передаются параметрами экземпляры класса `AbstractClass`, поскольку неизвестно точно, какой из классов-наследников следует туда передать, так как выбор происходит независимо от пользователя на основе генерирования квазислучаных чисел. Хотелось бы запустить метод без абстрактного объявления его в абстрактном классе и без последующего переопределения его в каждом классе-наследнике так, чтобы если он есть в наследнике, он выполнялся, а если нет – игнорировался.

```
abstract class AbstractClass{}

class Class1 extends AbstractClass{}
.
.
.
class ClassN extends AbstractClass {
    void Method(){...}
}

// скобочек и N+1 в оригинальном коде нет
class Class(N+1) {
    // какой-то из них может быть ClassN
    void Method2(AbstractClass a, AbstractClass b) {
        try{
            ClassN.Method();
        } catch(NoSuchMethodError e) {
            // ignore
        }
}
```

Comment: Что мешает сделать не абстрактный метод в абстрактном классе предке?

Comment: @YuriHeiko то, что он всегда будет выполняться в этом случае, так как будет существовать в каждом потомке?

Comment: Там где он не нужен переопределяй на пустой метод, там где нужен ничего делать не надо.